# jQuery, move ALL elements lower

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a serious issue: with jQuery, I have to move ALL elements toward down, because an advertisement banner must be put up there so that it wont cover anything. Its like havin a frameset at the top.
I was trying this:

```
jQuery('*').each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if ($this.css('position') === 'fixed' || $this.css('position') === 'absolute')
    {
        $this.css('margin-top', 80);
    }
});
```

but not all element are actually pushed.

Comment: Put all the content in a `div` which is set to `position: relative`, then apply `margin-top` to that div. Don't use JS for this as you're just creating more problems.

Comment: Wrap advertisement in a div and place it before the content like <div class="advertisement"></div><div class="rest-content"></div>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it wont work on "fixed" and "absolute" positioned elements

Comment: Then amend your HTML/CSS so that it will work. Using JS as a crutch for a flawed UI is a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Using a combination of your jQuery to add margin to fixed and absolute positioned elements, and padding-top to the body to cover static positioned elements I believe you can cover what you're after.

Notice I changed your selector in the jQuery to look for elements that are not of the 'ad' class.

This assuming your ad is absolutely positioned.

```js
$(':not(.ad)').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.css('position') === 'fixed' || $this.css('position') === 'absolute')
    {
        $this.css('margin-top', 80);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.content {
  position: static;
  padding: 0 110px;
}

.ad {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 728px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}

div.abs {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div.fxd {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  background: gray;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<p>Content in a static positioned block level div. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam venenatis elit nunc, a bibendum nisi volutpat id. Morbi pretium ultrices tortor sed porta. Praesent ullamcorper tristique luctus. Suspendisse sodales, est gravida accumsan sodales, urna turpis congue tortor, in ullamcorper justo magna et ex. Aliquam commodo, mi eget euismod volutpat, lorem lectus ultricies est, at congue velit ipsum vitae neque. Aenean consectetur ante lacus, ac iaculis sapien pulvinar a. Aenean porta porttitor faucibus. Sed nec metus vel enim suscipit placerat. Phasellus cursus pretium ex at venenatis.</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>Content in a static positioned block level div. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam venenatis elit nunc, a bibendum nisi volutpat id. Morbi pretium ultrices tortor sed porta. Praesent ullamcorper tristique luctus. Suspendisse sodales, est gravida accumsan sodales, urna turpis congue tortor, in ullamcorper justo magna et ex. Aliquam commodo, mi eget euismod volutpat, lorem lectus ultricies est, at congue velit ipsum vitae neque. Aenean consectetur ante lacus, ac iaculis sapien pulvinar a. Aenean porta porttitor faucibus. Sed nec metus vel enim suscipit placerat. Phasellus cursus pretium ex at venenatis.</p>
</div>

<div class="abs">This is a <strong>absolute</strong> positioned div at 0/0</div>
<div class="fxd">This is a <strong>fixed</strong> positioned div at 0/0</div>

<div class="ad"></div>
```

Comment: Don't know the ad height? then you should place the ad div before content, so it will increase height and push content dynamically when you add ad info...

Comment: @Shiv it wont work on "fixed" and "absolute" positioned elements

Comment: without a complete code example and not knowing how your elements are positioned (you never said), it was a best guess.

Comment: @John Smith edited solution to accommodate static, fixed, and absolute positioned elements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        /*
        // For Down all Element Viewport
        $('html').css('margin-top', 80);
        // or
        // For Down all Element Body

        $('body').css('margin-top', 80);
        */
        // For all fixed or absolute element

       var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
       var len = elems.length

       for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {

       if (window.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue('position') == 'fixed' || window.getComputedStyle(elems[i],null).getPropertyValue('position') == 'absolute') {
            elems[i].style.marginTop ='80px';
            }
        }
});

// If that content has a specific selector like ID or class, then use
$( your selector ).css("margin-top","80px");
```